# mutable data in scheme to return pairs where right element is the largest suffix matching a condition

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, mutable

I have this definition ***"sort left list"*** which is a list of pairs sorted according to the left element of each pair the left element must be a non-negative integer and the right component may be a value of any type

I have to write a procedure mkjump which takes as an argument a sorted list of non-negative integers,
sorted-lst = (x1 ... xn) and returns a left-sorted list:
sort left list = ((x1.y1)...(xn.yn)) such that: yi is the largest suffix of sort left list,
((xj . yj)...(xn . yn)) in which xk>(xi)^2 for all xk. For example:

```
   >(define lst (list 2 3 4 15 16 17))
   >(mkjump lst)
   >lst
    ( (2 (15) (16) (17))
    (3 (15) (16) (17))
    (4 (17))
    (15)
    (16)
    (17) )
```

The 6th element in res is (x6 . y6) where x6=17 and y6=null. The 3rd element in res is (x3 . y3),
where x3=4 and y3 is the list containing (x6 . y6), which is the largest suffix of res in which xk>(xi)^2
for all xk

How to write it?

Comment: Why does this require mutable data?

Comment: because after running this code if i run lst it return (2 3 4 15 16 17) so i think that i must use set!... and i got this question from mutable data questions

Comment: That doesn't mean you need mutable data at all.  The important thing is for `mkjump` to return the right answer, not to change `lst`, unless you assignment explicitly requires that `lst` change as well.

Comment: You can't do it with just set!.  You'll need to use set-car! and/or set-cdr! if you want to mutate the list that is passed into the procedure.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is should tag it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated previously you do not need mutable state to do your job. However, if you really want to use them you can easily change Keen's solution to get what you want. First you have to translate his code in a tail recursive way. You can begin with `mkjump`

```
(define (mkjump lst) (reverse (mkjump-tr lst '())))

(define (mkjump-tr lst sol)
  (if (null? lst)
      sol
      (mkjump-tr (cdr lst) 
                 (cons (cons (car lst) (wrapper (car lst) (cdr lst)))
                       sol)) ))
```

Then you can change `modmap`

```
(define (modmap proc lst) (reverse (modmap-tr proc lst '())))

(define (modmap-tr proc lst sol)
  (cond ((null? lst) sol)
        ((proc (car lst)) (modmap-tr proc 
                                     (cdr lst) 
                                     (cons (proc (car lst)) sol) ))
        (else (modmap-tr proc (cdr lst) sol))))
```

The tail recursive `mkjump-tr` will be translated in an iterative process. This is because it can be seen as a *while* loop. This enable you to create this loop with the `do` construction. This way `mkjump-tr` can be write as

```
(define (mkjump-tr lst sol)
  (do ((lst lst (cdr lst))
       (sol sol (cons (cons (car lst) (wrapper (car lst) (cdr lst)))
                       sol)) )
    ((null? lst) sol)
    ))
```

and `modmap-tr` can be translated as

```
(define (modmap-tr proc lst sol)
  (do ((lst lst (cdr lst))
       (sol sol (if (proc (car lst)) (cons (proc (car lst)) sol) sol)) )
    ((null? lst) sol)
    ))
```

But since we do not have recursive form, we can directly write these `do`'s in the former functions `mkjump` and `modmap`. So we get

```
(define (mkjump lst) 
  (do ((lst lst (cdr lst))
       (sol '() (cons (cons (car lst) (wrapper (car lst) (cdr lst)))
                       sol)) )
    ((null? lst) (reverse sol))
    ))

(define (modmap proc lst) 
  (do ((lst lst (cdr lst))
       (sol '() (if (proc (car lst)) (cons (proc (car lst)) sol) sol)) )
    ((null? lst) (reverse sol))
    ))
```

You could see some slight changes: `reverse` is added before `sol` and `sol` is initialize by the empty list in both case.

Finally, if you **really** want to see some `set!` somewhere, just add them by breaking the `do`-loop construction. Here is the solution for `mkjump`

```
(define (mkjump lst)
  (let ((elt 'undefined)
        (lst lst)
        (sol '()))
  (do () 
    ((null? lst) (reverse sol))
    (set! elt (car lst))
    (set! lst (cdr lst))
    (set! sol (cons (cons elt (wrapper elt lst)) sol))
    )))
```

I will let you change `modmap`. These two last modifications obfuscate the idea behind the algorithm. Therefore, it is a bad idea to change them this way, since they will not improve anything. The first modification can be a good idea however. So I will suggest you to keep the first modification.

Is this what have you expected ?

Answer (score 1):

I did this in MIT-scheme, hopefully it works in racket too.  I'm assuming you don't actually have to use mutation, given that your example doesn't depend upon it.

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (mkjump lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (cons (car lst) (wrapper (car lst) (cdr lst)))
        (mkjump (cdr lst)))))

(define (wrapper item lst)
  (modmap (lambda (x) 
         (if (< (square item) x)
             (list x)
             #f))
         lst))

(define (modmap proc lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((proc (car lst)) (cons (proc (car lst)) (modmap proc (cdr lst))))
        (else (modmap proc (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: thanks but i need it in imperative programming like using set! set-cdr! set-car!

Comment: Okay.  I'll think about how I can do this with set!